# Difference between .function() and .function().call in systemtap

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, systemtap

I am learning system tap utility to debug Linux Kernel.

Here is the sample code:

```
probe module("e1000").function("e1000_get*") {
printf("%s\n", ppfunc())
}

probe module("e1000").function("e1000_get*").return {
printf("%s \n", ppfunc())
}
```

What is the difference between

`probe module("e1000").function("e1000_get*")` and probe `module("e1000").function("e1000_get*").call`

I know that call is for function entry, is the above for both entry and exit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [systemtap](/questions/tagged/systemtap) [docs](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/langref.pdf):

> The `.function` variant places a probe near the beginning of the named
>   function, so that parameters are available as context variables.
>
> The `.return` variant places a probe at the moment of return from the
>   named function, so the return value is available as the $return
>   context variable. The entry parameters are also available, though the
>   function may have changed their values.

...

> The `.inline` modifier for `.function` filters the results to include only
>   instances of inlined functions. The `.call` modifier selects the
>   opposite subset.

So the `.call` modifier is to obtain just only "calls" (as such) from results.